# How to show that the one sided Laplace transform is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, laplace-transform, hardy-spaces

There is the claim that Laplace transform is a bounded linear operator on *pg 17* of  http://lall.stanford.edu/data/engr210a_0102/lecture6_2001_10_17_01.pdf

We assume that the Laplace transform operator $\Lambda: L_2[0,\infty) \to H_2$ where $H_2$ is Hardy space (see link)

We wish to show that $\exists \kappa \geq 0$ s.t. $$\|\Lambda f\|_{H_2} \leq \kappa \cdot \|f\|_{L_2}$$

I am not very familiar with the usual norm that is associated with $H_2$, can someone show how this claim is true?

Comment: This is the Parseval theorem for the Fourier transform : if $\hat{f}(\xi) = FT[f] =\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{-2i \pi \xi x} dx$ then $\|f\|_{L^2} = \|\hat{f}\|_{L^2}$. Now if $G(s) = \int_0^\infty g(x) e^{-sx}dx$ then $G(\sigma+2i \pi \xi) = \int_0^\infty g(x) e^{-\sigma x} e^{-2i \pi \xi x}dx = FT[g(.)e^{-\sigma .} 1_{. > 0}]$ and $\|G(\sigma+2i \pi .) \|_{L^2}  = \|g(.)e^{-\sigma .} 1_{. > 0}\|_{L^2}$ and $\|G\|_{H^2} = \sup_{\sigma >0} \|G(\sigma+ i .) \|_{L^2} = \sup_{\sigma > 0}\sqrt{2\pi}\|G(\sigma+ 2 i\pi .) \|_{L^2} = \sqrt{2\pi}\|g \ 1_{. > 0}\|_{L^2}$

Comment: And you meant $\|\Lambda f\|_{H^2} \le \kappa \ \|f\|_{L^2}$

Comment: @user1952009 Yes you are right and why not post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hardy space on the right half-plane $\Pi_{+}$ consists of all holomorphic functions $F$ on $\Pi_{+}$ that are in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ on every vertical line, with
$$
            \|F\|_{H^2}=\sup_{r > 0} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|F(x+iy)|^2dy < \infty\right)^{1/2} < \infty.
$$
If $f\in L^2[0,\infty)$, then
$$
               F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ts}f(t)dt \in H^2(\Pi_{+}).
$$
To prove this fact, the Plancherel theorem for the Fourier transform is applied to $F(s)$ as follows:
\begin{align}
     \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|F(x+iy)|^2dy&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-xt-iyt}f(t)dt\right|^2dy \\
   &=2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2xt}|f(t)|^2dt \\
   &\le 2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(t)|^2dt < \infty,\;\;\; f\in L^2[0,\infty).
\end{align}
From this you can show
\begin{align}
   \sup_{y > 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|F(x+iy)|^2dy&=2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(t)|^2dt, \\
       \|F\|_{H^2}&=2\pi\|f\|_{L^2[0,\infty)}.
\end{align}
In terms of the Laplace transform $\mathscr{L}$,
$$\|\mathscr{L}\{f\}\|_{H^2(\Pi^+)}=2\pi\|f\|_{L^2[0,\infty)}.$$